# Como colocar parte de um texto em negrito no Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Preciso mostrar um texto em uma interface GUI feita com TkInter, porém,
gostaria que apenas uma palavra no meio deste texto ficasse em negrito.

Estou usando da seguinte forma:

```
texto = Label(Frame, text="Texto qualquer com mais de 5 linhas", font= fonte qualquer, bold)
```

É claro que desta maneira o texto todo fica em negrito.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível mesmo com este *widget*. As soluções que as pessoas usam são usar um outro controle que renderiza o texto da forma como você deseja ou criar uma função que monte alguns *labels* como se fosse um só. è uma bela gambiarra mas costuma funciona. Uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22454125/221800) fez isto:

```
def customLabel(parent, row, column, bold, standard):
    cLabelFrame = Frame(parent)
    cLabelFrame.grid(row=row, column=column)
    Label(cLabelFrame, text=bold, font=('bold').grid(column=0)
    Label(cLabelFrame, text=standard).grid(column=1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/TkInterBold.py).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui uma resposta bacana de um usuário no Ggoogle, a ideia foi a seguinte:

Você pode dar uma olhada nas funções "tag_config" e "mark_set" do componente Tkinter.Text (aqui). No caso você teria de substituir seu componente Tkinter.Label por um Tkinter.Text (deixando ele desabilitado para edição claro...)

Fiz isso e deu bem certo, consegui colocar várias formatações, depois desativei as bordas, a edição e por fim coloquei a cor como a cor padrão.